# Unable to use Map Service in Web App Builder

Tags: arcgis-online, map-service, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I've published a symbolized data set as a Map Service from ArcMap to my company's Server. I've successfully added this service to our ArcGIS Online account, using the "Add Item from Web" function and pointing to the REST url of the service hosted on the server.

From there, I created a Web Map in AGOL that properly displays the uploaded map service. In the Web App Builder under Map--> Choose Web Map, I chose the aforementioned web map. The app will load for about 30 seconds, but fails to display the map. All that is shown is the initial base map. The Web Map title (AK_Field Map) and description are visible under the "Map" tab after I attempt to upload it, but there no data is displayed.

[image]

I've been able to create a Web Map using a published feature service, then successfully reference that Web Map in the Web App Builder. However, I want to be able to use a Web Map that displays a Map Service, not a Feature Service. Is this currently possible in the App Builder?

Answer (score 4):

Map Services are supported in the Web App Builder.

Here is what works for me:

1. Create a 'Web Map' in ArcGIS Online
2. Click 'Add Layer from Web', and paste in the URL to the Map Service.  (the URL should end in .../MapServer')
3. When you have finished configuring your map, click 'Save', and enter the proper metadata.
4. Next, click 'Share' and share it with your organization or public.
5. Click 'Make a Web Application> Web App Builder> Get Started'

This allows you to create the 'Web App Builder' application for that specific 'Web Map'.  Also Make sure the sharing settings are correct for both the Web Map and the Web App Builder application.